# MVC Button with a click event razor method and href WITHOUT httpost, get

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, button, razor

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult Detail(string type, string eventid)
    {
        var model = new Entiteit();
        var model2 = new CatalogusView();
        List<EventItem> films = model2.film();
        List<EventItem> talkshows = model2.talkshow();
        List<EventItem> tentoostellingen = model2.tentoonstelling();
        if (type == "film")
        {
            EventItem Film = model.EntiteitItem(films, eventid);
            List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
            items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = null, Value = null });
            foreach (Ticketitem ticket in Film.Eventtickets)
            {
                items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = ticket.Ticketnaam + " €" + ticket.Ticketprijs.ToString(), Value = ticket.Ticketvariantid.ToString() });
            }
            ViewData["Tickets"] = items;
            ViewData["Event"] = Film;
        }
```

View:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    EventItem item = ViewBag.Event;
    List<SelectListItem> tickets = ViewBag.Tickets;
}
<title>Detail</title>
<div class="entiteit">
    @if (item == null)
    {
        <div>ERROR 404</div>
        <div>-Deze pagina is alleen te bereiken via een selectie in de catalogus, er is nu geen info.-</div>
    }
    else if (item.Eventtype == "film")
    {
        <div>Naam: @item.Eventname</div>
        <div>Beschrijving: @item.Eventdescription</div>
        <div>Datum: @item.Eventdate</div>
        <div><img src="~/Content/Images/Films/@item.EventlocationImagepath" alt="@item.Eventname" /></div>
        <div>Lengte: @item.Eventduur</div>
        <div>Locatie: @item.Eventlocation</div>
        <img src="~/Content/Images/Locations/@item.EventlocationImagepath" alt="@item.Eventlocation" />
        <div>Genre: @item.Eventgenre</div>
        <div>Acteurs:@foreach(Acteuritem a in item.Eventacteurs) {@a.Acteurnaam @a.ActeurImagepath}</div>
        @Html.DropDownList("Tickets", tickets.Select(ticket => new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = ticket.Value,
            Text = ticket.Text,
            Selected = ViewData["Ticketselect"] == ticket.Value
        }))
        <div>
            Naam: @item.Eventreview
            Onderwerp: @item.Eventreviewonderwerp
            Bericht: @item.Eventreview
        </div>

        // HERE
    }
```

Right HERE I'd like to have a button that does the following Razor method:

```
@Winkelwagen.Instance.AddItem(item.EventID, item.Eventtype, ViewBag.Ticketselect, true, 1)
```

In which the following method gets the selected value from the item selected in the dropdownlist (which I put in the ViewBag.Ticketselect). After the item is added in Winkelwagen I'd like to href it to a specific page.

Due to the way other members in my group programmed the controllers I am unable to use HTTPPOST and GET. The controller ActionResult Detail(string type, string eventid) is already launched with an @Html.ActionLink from another page in which the the string type and eventid are put into the url and read by the controller. Using httppost or httpget would interrupt that process. Please help me out, I've wasted hours trying to solve this.

Comment: To run server-side code you need to post bask to the server.  If you can accomplish the same thing with client-side script then you could execute that from the button.  Why can't you use a POST or GET?

Comment: The amount of data being processed to `ViewBag` would pose some concerns, especially since it is all dynamic at run time.  However, for you to populate that correctly it requires a server side call.  Otherwise you'll need a hub or socket to open to poll the information from the server.

Comment: D Stanley because of the @Html.ActionLink from another page wich calls for that specific controller.

Comment: I'm not even sure if the dropdownlistlist i created automaticly updates the viewbag.Ticketselect everytime i change the selection in the dropdownlist.

Maybe there is another way for me to populate the dropdownlist in wich the item selected invokes a controller action that hrefs to another page and establishes the @winkelwagen method